# How does the following reducer function work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const objectFromPairs = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => ((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a), {});
console.log(objectFromPairs([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])); // {a: 1, b: 2}
```

I can't wrap my head around this. What does callback `(a, v) => ((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a)` do - isn't a reducer's callback supposed to be [just a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), why is there assignment followed by a comma then accumulator? How do I make sense of this?

When it's `(a, v) => a[v[0]] = v[1]`, why does it return `2`? Shouldn't it return `{a: 1}` on the first iteration, then `{b: 2}`, so shouldn't we end up with `{b: 2}` instead of just `2`?

Comment: Someone must have been trying to be annoyingly "clever" by writing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't wrap my head around this.

Understandable – it uses the relatively obscure (and proscribed!) [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). You can expand it to the equivalent statements to make it more readable:

```
const objectFromPairs = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => {
    a[v[0]] = v[1];
    return a;
}, {});
```

Still kind of an abuse of `reduce`, though. This is a generic function; it doesn’t have to be golfed.

```
const objectFromPairs = pairs => {
    const object = {};

    pairs.forEach(([key, value]) => {
        object[key] = value;
    });

    return object;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I think using decomposition is much nicer. However I don't see a problem with using `.reduce()` here; it'd be idiomatic in lots of FP environments.

Comment: @Pointy: It’s useful and I abuse it the same way occasionally too, but IMO as far as JavaScript FP goes it’s less idiomatic and more just an idiom (since use of JS’s imperative parts is standard, unlike the environments you’re referring to).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the inside and working out:

```
(a, v) => ((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a)
```

That's a reduce callback that takes an "accumulator" parameter (`a`) and a "value" parameter (`v`).  What the body of the function does is employ a comma operator expression statement to get around the need to use curly braces and an explicit `return`. The first subexpression in the comma operator expression, `(a[v[0]] = v[1])`, splits up a two-value array into a name for an object property and a value. That is, `v[0]` becomes a name for a property in the accumulator object, and `v[1]` is that property's value.

Now that's used in a `.reduce()` call made on an array, with `{}` as the initial value for the `.reduce()` accumulator. Thus, that function builds up properties with values taken from the source array, whose elements clearly need to be arrays themselves, because that's what the callback expects.

It looks like the key to your confusion is that comma operator. An arrow function in JavaScript only has an implied return value when its function body is just a single expression. The comma operator is a way to "cheat" a little bit: you can string together *several* expressions, with the overall result being the value of the *last* expression. For an arrow function, that's handy.